# Error with FirebaseAuthListener

Tags: android, textview

Error with FirebaseAuthListener in Android Studio.

```
Unexpected cast to EditText: layout tag was TextView
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you declared your view on the XML file as `TextView` while casting it to `EditView` on the activity.

You should change your view at the XML to `EditView` in order to have a password input (Contrasenia).